# Serializing class with IEnumerables - to use with Enyim Memcached

Tags: c#, serialization, memcached, enyim

I have a model that looks like:

```
[Serializable]
public class TemplatePageModel
{
    public PageModel Page { get; set; }
    public SidebarModel Sidebar { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class PageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SectionModel> Section { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SidebarModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ControlModel> Control { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SectionModel
{
    public string Order { get; set; }

    public string Editable { get; set; }

    public string Column { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I'm then trying to cache this in memcached using EnyimMemcached.

No exceptions are thrown, but the item isn't stored.
I've tracked this down to the fact that my TemplatePageModel class isn't serializable.

I tested this with this little snippet:

```
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
try
{
    b.Serialize(mem, result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //EXCEPTION HERE
}
```

It's complaining about my IEnumerable properties.

Actual error message is:

> Type
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,
>   System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[Desktop.Service.Model.ControlModel,
>   Dekstop.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as
>   serializable.

How can I get round this?

I was hoping not to have to serialize into json first, and de-serialize on the way out if possible....

Comment: define "complaining". Tell us the exact message. Actually, note that `BinaryFormatter` doesn't care whether something is `IEnumerable` - it is a field-level serializer. What it *might* care about is some things not being `[Serializable]`. So: what is `.Section` and `.Control` **actually** at runtime?

Comment: sorry, edited to show actual error message now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BinaryFormatter` is a field-level serializer. It won't care whether something is `IEnumerable` etc. It just cares about: "what is the ***actual*** object here? can I serialize it?". For example, an array or list is generally serializable. Some custom deferred sequence (maybe a filtered LINQ expression) is potentially *not* serializable.

Perhaps an even easier option: don't try to serialize complex expressions. So instead of:

```
obj.Controls = someQuery.Where(x => whatever).OrderBy(x => x.Foo);
```

do:

```
obj.Controls = someQuery.Where(x => whatever).OrderBy(x => x.Foo).ToArray();
```

An array (or list) is simple and trivially serializable.

Comment: Yep.. was using Linq to create object from XML... wasn't calling .ToList on a where.. was causing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly: The issue is because the IEnumerable might be holding a custom deferred sequence and therefore it can not be serialized?